# eigenvalue problem of $A^k$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of matrix $A$, we know $\lambda_1^k,\lambda_2^k,...,\lambda_n^k$ are eigenvalues of matrix $A^k$. Can $A^k$ have other eigenvalues?

I just read a proposition stating that $A^k$ only has eigenvalues $\lambda_1^k,\lambda_2^k,...,\lambda_n^k$. How to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $A^k$ cannot have any other eigenvalues. The simplest way to see this is to first transform $A$ into the Jordan canonical form, $A=PJP^{-1}$, where $J$ is a Jordan matrix. Then, $A^k = PJ^kP^{-1}$, and the diagonals of $J^k$ are the $k$-th powers of the diagonals of $J$.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the eigenvalue problem over the field of real numbers, then it can happen that $A$ has no real eigenvalues, but $A$ has.

Take the following matrix:
$$
A:=\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}, \quad A^2 = \pmatrix{-1 & 0 \\0 & -1}.
$$
$A$ has no real eigenvalues, but $A^2$ has real eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you so much! So It means the field should be complex when $A$ can be decomposed into Jordan canonical form, $A=PJP^{-1}$.